# How to create database for android application on remote webserver through java

Tags: android

i am devloping an android application thr java.i want to create or place the db on remote server,but not getting idea how to do this.plz help me .any code will be apriciated,
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The android device has a HTTP client, which in turn talks to the HTTP server. It is this server  manages the database perhaps using JDBC Drivers. Perhaps a more efficient way is to use RESTful WebServices and the data comes back to you as JSON or XML objects.
If I may suggest - please design first before seeking code.

Check these two links for details
http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/

www.slideshare.net/kewang/20100607-how-to-access-the-database-using-the-android